# How to determine servo signal encoding

Tags: signal, wiring, servo, encoding

I have a [TowerPro SG90](http://torqpro.com/?product=sg92r-7) servo which matches the "JR" brand wiring discussed [here](http://www.fatlion.com/sailplanes/servos.html) where the servo's 3 wires are as follows:

- Red is `+`
- Black is `-`
- Orange is `signal`

According to that article:

> The motor of an analog servo receives a signal from the servo amplifier (inside the servo) at 30 times a second. This pulsing signal tells the servo motor when to start rotating and which way to rotate.

To me this means that the signal wire expects signals that are **encoded** with both directional and positional information. I'm wondering where I can find the correct signal encoding for my particular servo, or any other servo for that matter. The manufacturer site does not provide any data sheet.

Comment: I found this "Position "0" (1.5ms pulse) is middle, "90" (~2ms pulse) is all the way to the right, "-90" (~1ms pulse) is all the way to the left." If you're using an Arduino: http://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/hacking-and-prototyping/motors-and-robotics/servo-motor-sg92r-micro (example sketch linked in there)

Comment: Thanks @DigitalNinja (+1) - I'm (obviously) new to electronics and have to say that I'm *thunderstruck* at how all these tiny components (not just servos: LEDs, switches, etc.) seem to be lacking any manufacturer documentation whatsoever! Is this common of the electronics industry, or did I just pick a rotten servo model? I guess I stunned that the manufacturer doesn't clearly document this stuff on their site, and that it is left to the good will/open source community to reverse engineer the component! Am I crazy or is this the norm?

Comment: You're welcome. Any respectable manufacturer will have documentation. In my experience it's all over the board though. Some provide excellent documentation and others have useless documentation or none. I think it just depends on the manufacturer and the part. Found a link to the datasheet, and all it has for operation is what I already posted lol. Electrical specs are in there though. http://www.datasheet4u.com/datasheet-pdf/TowerPro/SG90/pdf.php?id=791970

Comment: Servo signaling is pretty much a standard, although nobody seems to want to admit to it.

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams (+1) - is there a name/link for this standard by any chance? Can you confirm from DigitalNinja's datasheet4u.com link that this servo complies with that standard? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think there's a specific name for it, but the description seems accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd put it in an answer since that's all it is.

Position "0" (1.5 ms pulse) is middle, "90" (~2 ms pulse) is all the way to the right, "-90" (~1ms pulse) is all the way to the left.

Datasheet:  http://www.datasheet4u.com/datasheet-pdf/TowerPro/SG90/pdf.php?id=791970

Comment: Thanks @DigitalNinja (+1) - can you please see Ignacio's comment under the original question? Can you confirm there is a "servo standard" out there, and perhaps point me to some documentation on it? Thanks again!